# What does the verb phrase 'work ...in' mean?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

In this following context, what does the verb phrase 'work...in'' mean?

Is the difinition of ''work something in'': ''try to include or incorporate something in a text or speech.'' suitable for this verb phrase?

Context:

> Neither gifts to priests, nor self-castigation, nor performance of
> rites and ceremonies can **work** purification **in** him who is filled with
> craving.

Source: p. 5
Fundamentals of Buddhism
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: "...can be effective in purifying the person who is filled with craving".

Comment: It's not a very good translation, imho. Even as a nonce term, I don't really think ***to work purification [in X]*** is an acceptable "phrasal verb" for the sense ***to have a purifying effect [on X]***.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a non-idiomatic usage in a poor translation

Comment: Not a verb phrase, but simply the standard words "work" and "in".  The intended meaning of "work" here is "effectuate", but the whole sentence should probably be reorganized into a better translation somehow.

Comment: It's the word "work" and the word "in" separately. There's no joined meaning "work...in". "In" is just the preposition that *correlates* with "work" to indicate the object of the work.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, to **work** something **in** refers to doing something upon an object. The object receives the action that is being done, or *worked* into it.

Answer (score 0):

"work in" as a phrasal verb can mean (and could mean in this context) "To cause to penetrate" (Chambers). Although I agree that the quote is not particularly good English, so I wouldn't necessarily trust the translation. This meaning is used in recipes frequently, e.g. "Mix together to form a dough and work in the butter."